# angular ui tree displaying raw values (i.e directly printing json data which comes from spring mvc)

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

this is my tree.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" />
<script src="resources/js/controller/AutoConfigController.js"></script>
    <script src="demo/jquery.2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="demo/angular.1.2.29.js"></script>
    <script src="demo/bootstrap.3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="demo/ui-bootstrap-tpls.0.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="demo/prettify.1.0.1.js"></script>

    <link  href="demo/bootstrap.3.1.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link  href="demo/prettify-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="angular-tree-control.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tree-control.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tree-control-attribute.css">

<style type="text/css">
.header {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #444980;
}

.head-container {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: auto;
}

.header h1 {
    color: #fffffa;
    font-size: 60px
}

.header h2 {
    color: #fffffa;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal
}

.example-caption {
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 12px
}

.docs-body {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: auto auto 50px;
}

.docs-footer {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-top: #e5e5e5
}

.tab-pane {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px
}

.nav li.active a {
    background-color: #f8f8f8
}

pre.code {
    border: none;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Consolas, 'Liberation Mono', Courier, monospace;
}

.docs-sidenav {
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.docs-sidenav>li>a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #999;
    padding: 4px 20px;
}

.docs-sidenav>li.active>a {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #563d7c;
    border-left: 2px solid #563d7c;
    padding-left: 18px;
}

.docs-sidenav>li>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #563d7c;
    border-left: 1px solid #563d7c;
    padding-left: 19px;
}

.type-hint-object {
    background: #999;
}

.type-hint-boolean {
    background: rgb(18, 131, 39);
}

.type-hint-number {
    background: rgb(189, 63, 66);
}

body, html {
    background: none !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}

#mydiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 30em;
    height: 18em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
</style>
<body ng-controller="AutoConfigController">

    <div id="mydiv">
        <form>
            <div>
                <input id="treeSearchText" type="text" />
                <button id="searchTree" class="btn">Search</button>

            </div>
        </form>
<treecontrol class="tree-classic" tree-model="techList" on-selection="showSelected(node)">
     {{techList}}
 </treecontrol>

<script>

                  angular.module('SuperAdminReveal')
    .directive('treeControl', function () {
        return {
            template: '<div class="treeControl" ng-transclude></div>',
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (e) {
                    if (e.target.tagName === "LI" && e.target.childElementCount) {
                        $(e.target).toggleClass('collapsed');
                    }
                })
            }
        };
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my treescontroller.java: from here i am returning json value to tree.jsp

```
package com.reveal.web.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.reveal.web.controller.EnsureCapacity.Technology;

@Controller
public class TreesController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/mytree",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        return "tree";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getTechList", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public @ResponseBody List<EnsureCapacity.Technology> getTechList(){
        EnsureCapacity ensureCapacity = new EnsureCapacity();
        List<EnsureCapacity.Technology> techList = ensureCapacity.getTechList();
         return techList;
        } 

    }
output:
```

Selected Node : [{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 1","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 1.1","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 1.2","id":0},{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 2","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 2.1","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 2.2","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 2.3","id":0},{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 3","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 3.1","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 3.2","id":0},{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 4","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 4.2","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 4.3","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 4.4","id":0},{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 5","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 4.5","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 4.6","id":0},{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 6","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.1","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.2","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.3","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.4","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.5","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.6","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.7","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 6.8","id":0},{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 7","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 7.1","id":0},{"pId":0,"techName":"Node 8","id":1},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.1","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.2","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.3","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.4","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.5","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.6","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.7","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.8","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.9","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.10","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.11","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.12","id":0},{"pId":1,"techName":"Node 8.12","id":0}]
this is displaying on browser how to make it in treeview .
I am using angular-tree-control module

Answer (score 0):

```
// Update tree control below

<treecontrol class="tree-classic" tree-model="techList" on-selection="showSelected(node)">
     {{node.techName}} ({{node.id}} ) {{$index}}
 </treecontrol>
```